# Sentencias preparadas en MSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

**Editado**
Agrego el ajax donde hago la petición

```
$.ajax({
        //tipo de peticion puede ser
        type: "POST",
        //url del php
        url: "pcService.php",
        //separado por comas
        data: {
            id: idPC,
            comando: 1,
        },
        //tipo de dato a recibir
        dataType: "json",
        //en el caso de algun error que mande un mensaje
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            swal(
                'Error!',
                errorThrown,
                'error'
            );
        },
        //si hay conexion obtenemos la data que nos envia el php
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           console.log(data);
        }

    });
```

Tengo el la siguiente función.

```
$comando = $_POST["comando"];
switch ($comando){
 case 1:
    //get Asignaciones
     $idPc = $_POST["id"];
    echo asignacionPcLista($idPc);
    break;

}

function asignacionPcLista($idPc){
 GLOBAL $bd;
 try {
     $arrayInfo = array();
     $conexion = $bd->getConecction();
     $query = "SELECT sp.nombre,ac.fecha FROM soporte_compu AS c 
                    INNER JOIN soporte_asignacion_compu AS ac ON ac.SOPORTE_COMPU_idSOPORTE_COMPU = c.idSOPORTE_COMPU 
                    INNER JOIN soporte_personal AS sp ON sp.idSOPORTE_PERSONAL = ac.SOPORTE_PERSONAL_idSOPORTE_PERSONAL 
                    WHERE c.idSOPORTE_COMPU = ? AND ac.status = ?";
     $stmt = $conexion->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bind_param("is", $idPc,$estatus = '1');
     $stmt->execute();
     $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
     $stmt->close();
     array_push($arrayInfo,["asignaciones"=>$resultSet->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)]);
     //array_push($arrayInfo,["informacion"=>getPC($idPc)]);
     return json_encode($arrayInfo, true);
 } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     return json_encode(["error" => "Error al modificar la asignación, " . $e->getMessage()], true);
 }
}
```

Esta sentencia me obtiene todos los usuarios que tienen asignada una pc.
**Cuando se trata de un usuario si me arroja bien los datos, el detalle esta en que cuando son mas de un por ejemplo: 5 usuarios no me arroja nada.**

Aqui muestro el resultado que deberia de estar esperando, pero cuando quiero obtenerlo en php no me arroja nada, solo arroja cuando hay un usuario en esa asignación pero cuando son muchos asignadas no me muestra nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que la función `fetch_array()` solo te devuelve la primer fila de los resultados, tendrías que hacer un volcado con algo como un while:

```
$stmt->execute();  
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();  
$stmt->close();  
$x = 0;  
$arrayFinal = Array();  
while($temporal = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {  
    $arrayFinal[$x] = $temporal;  
    $x ++;  
}  
array_push($arrayInfo,["asignaciones"=>$arrayFinal]);  
//array_push($arrayInfo,["informacion"=>getPC($idPc)]);  

return json_encode($arrayInfo, true);
```

También te recomiendo que cuando quieras saber si un array se está pasando u obteniendo correctamente, utilices `print_r()` en tu entorno de desarrollo para visualizar la estructura de tu array, y así entender un poco mejor lo que podría estar pasando al volcar los datos. Por ejemplo:

```
print_r($arrayInfo);
```